# (Firebase's Firestore || Flutter) How to get total of an identical field in all maps in a document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have identical fields in `maps` in a `document`. I want to get a `sum` total of all `map` fields.

Here a sample of the structure:

```
1: {
Name: "banana",
Price: 50,
Weight: 70
}

2: {
Name: "apple",
Price: 80,
Weight: 30
}
...
```

I'll have multiple `maps` like these in a `document`.

Now, how to get `sum` total of all `fruits`' `price` or `weight`?

i.e.

**Total Price**: 50 + 80 = 130

**Total Quantity**: 70 + 30 = 100

Is it possible to do so without mentioning the name of the `map`? Since i'll have multiple `maps` in a `ducument`. If not, what's an alternative structure?

Here is my structure for now:

```
          Stores (collections)
                    |
         Products (sub collection)
          |                    |
Fruits (Document)      Vegetables (Document)
       |
Maps with tittle fruit id
     |_ Name
     |_ Price
     |_ Weight
```

Note: My database is about something else, not exactly this. So dont try to make sense of the query.

Comment: Do you only wan to do this sum at the level of one document or cross-documents?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec One Document

Answer (score 0):

You want to sum up the total of all map fields in **one Firestore document**.

There are two possible approaches:

**1. Sum up when reading**

When you read (i.e. query) a Firestore document you get ALL the fields of this document. It is therefore easy to read the desired fields and to sum them up.

**2. Sum up when writing**

When you write create the document you have all the values of the map. You can very well do the sum and write the result to one or more specific fields.
It may be a bit more complex when updating, if you only update some of the map values. You may need to query the document before updating it, in order to have all the values and be able to calculate the updated sum.

Comment: My use case suits sum up when reading, Is it possible to read and sum all maps in one document with identical fields even though I don't define Map name in the query? (like a wildcard)

Ik its sounds wierd, but what I am doing is I am creating a sync method from SQFLITE to FireStore, where all rows in sqlite are stored as maps in a Firestore document. So Map name will be sqlite table's primary key, which I won't have while querying in Firestore for sum.

Comment: Please let me know if you didn't get what I am saying, I'll explain it better in Question as an update. Thanks a lot for your help btw, it means a lot.

Comment: Not sure to understand your comments. If you save a data item in a Firestore document. field you need to know the name of the field. If in this field you store a map, you also need to know the name of the map elements, so you should not have any problem to loop over the map elements and sum them up.